# MPI_Bcast Segmentation Fault 139

Tags: c, mpi

I'm trying MPI_Bcast to broadcast message to multiple nodes and I'm getting segmentation fault with sometimes error: 139 or error: 255. Following is my code:

```
char proposal[20];
char rep;
int size, rank;
printf("1\n");
//Initialization
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

printf("init\n");
//Getting size and rank of processes
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
printf("abc\n");
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

printf("2\n");
//Proposal message for root node
if(rank == 0)
{
    printf("string copy\n");
    strcpy("Choose a or b\n", proposal);
}

printf("3\n");
//Broadcasting message
MPI_Bcast(proposal, 20, MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
printf("broadcast\n");
printf("%s", proposal);
```

I would really appreciate if I can get any help.

Answer (score 2):

`strcpy` first parameter is the destination, and the second is the source. You have it reversed.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem because I removed that part and the error is still there.

Comment: That is clearly a problem. Is it *the* problem? I don't know. The code is incomplete and there is no additional visible problems.

Comment: It can be a problem may be it is but I changed it and the error is still there. As far as code is concerned. Yes it is complete except for the libraries I included and MPI_Finalize() at the end

Comment: So what is your `proposal` would be if you remove that part?

Comment: If `strcpy()` is used in wrong order, it can fail. If `strcpy()` is removed, `proposal` is not initialized and `printf("%s\n",proposal);` can fail.

Comment: I just restarted the machine several times and it works now.